# use of cvShowImage with namespace

Tags: c++, opencv

What is the name of the namespace that implements cvCreateImage? How do i reach this method by using namespace?

```
<namespace>.cvShowImage("Sample Program", frame);
```

Comment: what language are you using ?

Comment: i am using c++ languge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the whole outdated c-api does *not* live in any namespace.

if you're just starting with opencv, avoid it(any cv* functions), use the c++ api (namespace cv) instead.

so, your example would translate to :

```
cv::VideoCapture cap(0); // 1st cam
while ( cap.isOpened() )
{
    cv::Mat frame;
    if ( ! cap.read(frame) )
         break;

    cv::imshow("Sample Program", frame);
    cv::waitKey(30);
}
```

Comment: How do i capture from camera 0 by using c++ api then?

Comment: More appropriate terms would be: "C API", and "C++ Wrapper/API". C API is not outdated!

Comment: @Thrustmaster  read this : http://answers.opencv.org/question/17546/opencv-will-drop-c-api-support-soon/

Comment: @B... Thanks for the link, I take that statement back.:)